# Improve performance with Apache poi(XSSF user model api) and jdbc batch

Tags: java

Please suggest some way to improve the performance?

Actually our project has below mentioned process,

1. Load the huge xlsx file and validating that value by using sax parser xml.
2. If validation success then will store into database.

This is the routine process. Every day, we will load more file.

Currently using following techniques:

1. Reading large file using Apache poi(XSSF user model api) and validating through xml by using sax parser.
2. then storing into JDBC batch and executing it.
3. Database oracle 11g

So my question is, still any better way is there to improve performance?

Please advice.

Comment: Can you post more details about your current implementation, like if you are using a concurrent approach or something like that ?

Comment: thanks for reply,reading large xlsx file using apache poi user model api and then validating the file values by using xml xpath ,if records are matched then will add in jdbc batch finally i will execute the batch statement .so this is the frequent process

Answer (score 0):

If where you and mi primary objective where optimice the execution time of the whole process i would begin making partitions of the xlsx to be able to process more than one block of data at the same time, this part is easy.

After that, if the data is not depend on the order of execution, began with launching multiple process in parallel, with spring batch or just javax.batch api you can do that, this will allow your application to scale better and reduce the execution time N parts, being N the number of concurrent process that you launch. Each process should handle only one job just like now i think you are doing, but the parallelism will improve your execution time.

At the same time if you have a bit more time, instead using apache poi, you can use a csv instead a xlsx and don't do the transformation phase to reduce more time and memory usage

Comment: ya thanks but user only will upload the xlsx file ,can we convert xlsx into csv programatically within seconds even 10 lakhs record?i think apache poi (user model) usually will convert into csv then will read rit?

Comment: and how to do partitioned the block of data in xlsx?

Comment: You can partition the data based on the number of concurrent batch instances that you are going to have, ex : xlsx with 1000 lines, 10 batch process = 1000/10 lines per process, so you read the whole xlsx or using ranges, and launch each batch with a subset of lines

Comment: thanks for reply if u dont mine can u post example code for reference how to partition the data in xlsx.

Comment: thanks we are using struts 2 framework with spring integration for web application.

Comment: I don't have enough time to proper code a full example bur here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/ you can find one really similar, following this should be easy, the only thing you have to do is read the xlsx lines, and based on the number o lines distribute subset of lines per each process, on the example they use a database, but you can configure the Item reader to work with an xlsx out of the box, read the spring batch doc

Comment: ya i will refer that website but i checked in spring doc they are giving option to read from excel using poiitemreader but i couldnt find that maven dependency anywhere can u help me to work with xlsx.

Comment: You can find that class here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/3.0.7.RELEASE

Comment: can u check that jar file,it doesnt have that poiitemreader class

Comment: you are wright, it's an extension https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel

Comment: Hi i have configured as per the instructions now it is configured but i have list of doubts please clarify 1.is this extension reliable ?can we use this for enterprise application 2. is it low memory consume because apache streaming api is low memory consume.